# Cockpit plugins are available for Community and Enterprise Edition of Camunda?

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

Is it only avaliable to Enterprise Edition?
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/webapps/cockpit/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, plugins can also be used in the Community Edition.

For features, that are exclusive to the Enterprise Edition, have a look at this page:

https://camunda.com/de/enterprise/